# buildozer setup hangs at “compile platform” segment

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I ran

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

and then it is just hanging on # Compile Platform

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
```

Do not know what to do. Does it should be hanging like that? It has been 2 hours right now. It is basic project using kivy. Just to check whether android development with it works.

Comment: Add `--verbose` (I think) to possibly see more output. It shouldn't normally take this long, but if it hasn't actually crashed then I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this issue, it's possible that you screwed something up with your Buildozer installation. Try to use a VM Image: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html

Then I removed the Buildozer cache with the following command:

```
rm -rf ~/.buildozer/android/packages
```

And it worked :D

**Note:** Change your log level to 2 or use

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

to see more output.